# Partition / too full – Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, partition, kde

I am currently installing Arch Linux in my VMware non-pro/commercial use. 
I downloaded the latest Linux .iso available in the website. 
This is my third/fourth time installing Arch Linux
and 2nd time installing within today due to a problem:

Since I was a beginner in Arch, I was following the [Install Arch Linux in VMware Workstation](https://linuxconfig.org/install-arch-linux-in-vmware-workstation#:%7E:text=First%2C%20download%20the%20Arch%20Linux,and%20then%20New%20Virtual%20Machine%20.&text=Under%20Install%20Operating%20System%20from,Linux%20ISO%20then%20click%20next%20.&text=Click%20Linux%20under%20Guest%20Operating%20System%20.) guide. 
On my first attempt I gave **20GB** disk space in my VMware settings. 
Just like the guide I divided this on this partition: *on my first attempt,*
sda1 has 500M with EFI, sda2 has 18.5GB with Linux File System, and sda3 has 1GB with Swap type. While on *my 2nd attempt* I gave **200GB** disk space in my VMware setting and gave bigger value on sda2 (with 100GB) and sda3 (with 2GB).

-----here is the problem now-----

I did follow all steps properly and as soon as I rebooted my Linux (as instructed),
I immediately tried to install KDE Plasma or GNOME as my Desktop Environment using [How to Properly Install and Setup KDE Plasma on Arch Linux](https://itsfoss.com/install-kde-arch-linux/) and [How to Install and Configure KDE Plasma Desktop in Arch Linux](https://www.debugpoint.com/kde-plasma-arch-linux-install/). 
However, no progress is being made
since whenever I'm trying to install, it says: "Partition / too full"
and the download/ installation is being cancelled—this is where I am stuck. 
It keeps saying Partition / too full at any of the guides there.

I would like to ask, what could be the problem why it keeps saying partition / is too full when I gave 20 (first attempt) and 200G (second attempt)? 
And how can I resolve this?

Here is the `lsblk` and `df -h` output as well as the `cfdisk /dev/sda` output:

[image]

[image]

And lastly, here is the output that I'm having problem with Partition.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand. You are showing that your root partition is only 256M. It is your `/dev/sda2` that is 200G but that isn't root (`/`), it is `/mnt`. Also, please don't follow random tutorials for Arch. Arch has probably the best documentation of the Linux world, please follow the Arch Wiki. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide

Comment: You're probably trying to install this into the *installer*, instead of into the *installed* (or: in the process of being installed) system, whose root file system is currently mounted under /mnt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to install these packages on your live environnement, ie. the iso installer.

If you want to install something during arch installation, you need to do that **after** this step:

```bash
arch-chroot /mnt
```

Please follow carefully the [installation manual](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Installation_guide) to have better comprehension of the differents steps. As @Terdon said, this without any doubt the best documentation you can find on this topic.

I recommend installing optionnal software like desktop environnement after installation completed, and after reboot.

Maybe you accidentally booted up again on the installer instead of booting on hard disk...
You may need to check your BIOS boot config.

Comment: Thanks. okay i found my biggest mistake. since i rebooted, i need to reenter arch-chroot /mnt then install KDE Plasma there. . that explains it. thank you for the help(i would love to add upvote to all of everyone her but im too new and low rep. however all of everyone's answer are solving my problem).

Comment: No worries, thanks for your feedback ! Why do you reboot inside installer to install KDE ? You can install it from the newly installed system, isn't ?

Comment: i think thats because i was confused on what and where i am now. since when i was using Mint there isn't something similar to this, atleast most of my experience. i do have basic idea of File System of Linux but i got confused on Arch-Chroot, either because of the environment, different installation process plus lack of serious experience. this is the first time i seriously building Arch compare to my previous attempt. i didn't even realize i was actually in the installer.  so i got confused. so its really lack of experience.....should have read the wiki of arch instead. lesson learned!

Comment: Yeah no problem, this is by doing errors we learn ;-).
Arch is very good for that !

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to install this into the installer, instead of into the installed (or: in the process of being installed) system, whose root file system is currently mounted under /mnt.

Finish your installation, then boot into the actual system you've just installed, and *then* install whatever you want to have. (You could actually do this earlier, that's true, but there's literally zero upside to that if you're doing a manual install. So, install arch, boot into your newly installed system, install the software you're missing.)